# Sending HTML emails from Node.JS using MailGun

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailgun

I send email notifications to my users from my app but currently I only send it as a text. I would like to send it HTML emails which are styled.

**Currently I tried this:**

```
var data = {
              from: 'my app',
              to: user.email,
              subject: 'Welcome',
              html: '<div style="width: 500px; height: 400px: background: #ebebeb; color: #ddd"><p>Hi  + "user.firstName" + \n ,this email is to inform you that has added their bio to the knowledge Base \n</p></div>'
           };
```

Compiling the above code does not work, it does not like the styles I have put in. 
I have created a separate HTML file within my local directory for each type of email I want send and I would like to be able to attach that html file to my email.

**Something like this:**

```
var data = {
              from: 'my app',
              to: user.email,
              subject: 'Welcome',
              html: welcomeToSiteEmail.html
           };
```

Is the above possible? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also ran into this and the `mailgun-js` module didn't support the very important `template` property (I believe this is what you want, instead of the `html` property). I found this github project https://github.com/mailgun/node-prelaunch has a working solution where they combine the templating of nodemailer with the mailgun-js transport. If this answers your question, I can pull out the code which specifically handles this and create an answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `mailgun-js` together with `mailcomposer` to send HTML formatted emails.

The [mailgun-js docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js) include an example:

```
var domain = 'mydomain.mailgun.org';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ apiKey: "YOUR API KEY", domain: domain });
var mailcomposer = require('mailcomposer');

var mail = mailcomposer({
  from: 'you@samples.mailgun.org',
  to: 'mm@samples.mailgun.org',
  subject: 'Test email subject',
  body: 'Test email text',
  html: '<b> Test email text </b>'
});

mail.build(function(mailBuildError, message) {

    var dataToSend = {
        to: 'mm@samples.mailgun.org',
        message: message.toString('ascii')
    };

    mailgun.messages().sendMime(dataToSend, function (sendError, body) {
        if (sendError) {
            console.log(sendError);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Alternately, you could check out [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) on npm. It's a great package: easy to use and extensive documentation. With nodemailer, you can do something like this

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' },
      auth: {
        user: '<Mailgun SMTP login>',
        pass: '<Mailgun SMTP password>'
      }
    });

transport.sendMail({
        from: '<Mailgun SMTP login>',
        to: ['bob@example.com', 'bill@foobarbaz.com', /*etc*/],
        subject: 'Fancy Email',
        text: 'still send some text to be on the safe side',
        html: { path: 'path/to/email.html' }
    }, callback)
// also returns a promise.
```

However, I would suggest being very thorough in your design of html emails. Writing html email is very different from html in the web. There's a much wider variety of email clients that do will render your html differently, and some, Outlook for Windows and gmail web for example, will not treat your html very nicely. [Litmus](https://litmus.com/) has some nice resources regarding best practices for designing html emails.

My suggestion would be to use [foundation for emails](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foundation-emails) for your styling, use [inky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inky) to simplify the semantics of writing html email, and [inline-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css) to inline all of your styles. Even if you use alternate methods of sending the mail, check out these resources for designing it. They will save you lots of headache.

Comment: Great extra tips - I've used Litmus for a long time - what a time saver! Also I just found this for storing the auth credentials: https://www.npmjs.com/package/buttercup

Comment: I had to use "pass" not "password" for the SMPT transport options.

Comment: I would strongly second Hayden Braxton I use mailchimp to layout out HTML - their wysiwyg email creator is excellent and renders very well. You can send yourself a test email and then view the HTML to extract it.